# I am trying to store File path(4 files) and Files metadata to hashmap.how to do that? i am using Tika API

Tags: java, apache-tika

[image: C]

Using TikaApi i am trying to read xlsx file path and xlsx file metadata but i am not sure how to store files path and metadata into hashmap for further access or reading from hashmap .
Please help !

Comment: It might be more practical to put the actual code instead of an image, so please consider it.

Answer (score 0):

Use a HashMap with the File as key and Metadata as value (or viceversa, depends on what you want). Then put the file and the corresponding metadata in the hashmap.

```
HashMap<File, Metadata> hashMap = new HashMap<File, Metadata>();
hashMap.put(file, metadata);
```

Also, it would be a better practice to use `List<String> l = new ArrayList<String>();` (or even better, `List<File>`) instead of `List l = new ArrayList();`

PD: You have some unindented code in the for loop. Indenting it might make it more readable.

Comment: String[] metadataNames = metadata.names(); map.put(fileArray[i],metadataNames);
map.get(i);
The above is not working , not printing metadata

Comment: `get(i)` retrieves the value corresponding to the key `i`, which is a number. However, you are using File as the key, so you should do `get(fileArray[i])` instead.

Comment: It works fine with get(fileArray[i]) for file path but 
still not able to get values of 'key' i.e for every key i am not able to extract the corresponding value.

Comment: @Twiety while you iterate over 4 files to to build `hashMap` you will always have key, you should build a function that should return ArrayList that should store the metadata values, and then using get(i) you should be able to retrieve the value of each key i.e. the metadata paked in a list

Comment: Exactly, on a similar situation, I have two `ArrayList`s. Then, to get the key correspoding to a certain value, I do `keyList.get(valueList.indexOf(value))` (or viceversa), though in your case you can just do `keyList.get(i)`.